# How size of the array is changing in the list?

Tags: c++, arrays, list, data-structures

After adding a new index, the size of the array is changed from `n` to `n+1`. I have declared my array with size of `n`. When I added a new index it is automatically changing its size from `n` to `n+1`?

```
main()
{
    int n=5;
    int a[n];

    // input in array
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    // add number at start
    n=n+1;
    int k=n-1;
    for (int i=k;i>0;i--)
    {
        a[i]=a[i-1];
    }
    a[0]=8;
```

Comment: int n=5;
    int a[n];  was this compiled??

Comment: There is no size adjustment going on. You simply have a bug.

Comment: I am guessing you're asking about out of bounds access, but it is difficult to know for sure. So if you're asking about something else, please clarify your question.

Comment: @juanchopanza When I run this code I am not getting any error at all. if there is some error then definitely I will ask about that.. but this error free code compiled and run in Dev C++

Comment: @juanchopanza I am asking about the size of `a[n]`. in the start I have declared that size of `a[n]` and when insert new element in the list at start then compiler itself changed the size of `a[n]` to `a[n+1]`?

Comment: OK, then the duplicate covers it.

Comment: @juanchopanza  I have checked the duplicate question it was using gcc but I am not using that

Comment: @DeeKhan It doesn't matter. It is undefined behaviour.

Comment: as I am not getting any error, so the undefined behavior is not error actually, right?